# Swift enum values not settable

Tags: swift, enums, setter, computed-properties

I am adding some syntactical sugar to my app, and I came across an 'inconsistency'. There is probably good reason for it, but is there  way to clean the implementation a little.
I a doing this to provide a single place to set/get some properties.

```
enum MyType: String {
    case Unknown, First, Second

    var enabled: Bool {
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: self.rawValue) }
        get { return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: self.rawValue) }
    }

}
```

Now I can use the enum values to get the defaults

```
if MyType.First.enabled {
    ........
}
```

But I cannot directly set the value:

```
MyType.First.enabled = true
```

elicits 'cannot set property, First is not assignable'

but I can get away with

```
var type = MyType.First
type.enabled = true
```

Is there a simple way to use the one-line method?

Comment: You're looking for `nonmutating set`, I don't know if it's worth writing the answer, because you just need to add `nonmutating` keyword before `set` keyword. If someone can expand this into complete answer, please do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that `enum`s are value types, so when you call the setter of `enabled` on `MyType.First`, you mutate `First` as well. If you don't assign value types to a mutable variable explicitly, they are considered immutable. This is why `if MyType.First.enabled {...}` doesn't work, but

```
var type = MyType.First
type.enabled = true
```

does work.

If you mark the setter as `nonmutating`, the issue is resolved, since the compiler will now know that you aren't mutating a value type when calling the setter on its property.

```
enum MyType: String {
    case unknown, first, second

    var enabled: Bool {
        nonmutating set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: self.rawValue) }
        get { return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: self.rawValue) }
    }

}
```

P.S.: the Swift naming convention for `enum` cases is lowerCamelCase, since they are not types themselves and only types should be UpperCamelCase. I've modified your `MyType` `enum` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

By adding the `nonmutating` keyword to the `set` method you are telling the compiler that the `set` method will *not* modify the enclosing type, that is the enum `MyType` in this case

```
enum MyType: String {
    case Unknown, First, Second

    var enabled: Bool {
       nonmutating set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: self.rawValue) }
       get { return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: self.rawValue) }
    }
}
```